# Imported image darkened after imported to "image" node in compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes

Short story, after attempting to import an image into the compositing node "image," it was darkened in a odd way in blender.

Original Image vs Seen in Blender

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the the image and what settings are you using for the color management section?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Check the box exposure value [image]

As you can see I had -2.610 value and the picture was darkened (like in your screenshots).

Try to set this value to 0. If the value changes back to previous number after a second, check your addons. As for me, I could set it to 0 only after disabling my Photographer addon
[image]